# Passing the output of a variable to a command and running for command wthin a script

Tags: bash, variables, nginx, echo, plesk

Trying to figure out this confusing coding for Plesk. Plesk offers an event handler and pre-made variables within its system. (Plesk event handler documentation: http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/12.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=67897.htm"

In a nutshell, I am trying auto enable nginx for a customer who creates a new domain by using the Domain created (variable name: NEW_DOMAIN_NAME) variable to automatically "paste" the ouput into a specific command, and then for the command to be automatically ran. This is how it works:

1. Customer chooses to create domain, this triggers the event handler
2. NEW_DOMAIN_NAME is the variable to retrieve the customers entered domain (lets use domain.com)
3. In the event handler, I'd like to execute this command after retrieving the created domain name:

/usr/local/psa/bin/subscription --update-web-server-settings domain.com -nginx-serve-static true -nginx-serve-php true

In order to retrieve the domain name, I am assuming you use echo $NEW_DOMAIN_NAME. For some reason I cannot get this to work at all. What I do know is when you echo $NEW_DOMAIN_NAME >> /tmp/testfile.log the output prints domain.com and saves the document.

Coding that I tried in command line of plesk event handler is below:

```
    domainname="$NEW_DOMAIN_NAME"

/usr/local/psa/bin/subscription --update-web-server-settings echo "$domainname" -nginx-serve-static true -nginx-serve-php true
```

When asking for support from the Plesk forum, unfortunately they do not want to provide the appropriate code for some reason. But here was their response:

"you have to define in your command WHERE you want the variable "NEW_DOMAIN_NAME" should be taken from - the subscription utility doesn't know this by default, because the variable is not used in any parameter definition with this utility."

Here is what the subscription utility file shows:

```
    #!/opt/psa/bin/sw-engine-pleskrun
<?php
    die("The file {$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']} is part of Plesk distribution. $
    __sw_loader_pragma__('PLESK12');
?>
�v�9�9x^M��ƇTH�ڇh��u-2п��(���F^NؿA^Q�^U�UѺ=X ^]^N����
Em�I�VtQh$������֞<T^T��)H�I^N<^LK})[A�^\��+c�^?��AҖˇҁ]�%�^_.�ށF؁ɁUāk,�$ү�Ưw�w^^K�$
```

Please advise, thanks guys!

Comment: Could you paste some code please, I don't fully understand what it is you want. What have your tried? How does the variable get set? By executing `some command >> some_file` all standard output will be *appended* to some_file.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the repsonse and sorry for the confusion. This is what I have tried to use so far
COMMAND BELOW: 

domainname="$NEW_DOMAIN_NAME"

/usr/local/psa/bin/subscription --update-web-server-settings echo "$domainname" -nginx-serve-static true -nginx-serve-php true

I believe I may be executing this incorrectly since of course it isn't working

Comment: Add the code to the question. You can format it using four leading spaced before each line so it's easily readable! The more clear your question is, the more chance somebody will answer it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `echo` and don't assign `$NEW_DOMAIN_NAME` to `$domainname`; just use `$NEW_DOMAIN_NAME` itself:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/subscription --update-web-server-settings "$NEW_DOMAIN_NAME" -nginx-serve-static true -nginx-serve-php true
```

The shell will place the contents of `$NEW_DOMAIN_NAME` as a command-line argument.  This should work.

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for the support.. please check the revision up top :)